# Expresso Store Shipping Required?

Tags: expresso-store

My site does not have any items that will be shipped. I have no shipping methods set up. I have no shipping fields present in the checkout. The orders won't submit, and the error messages I'm getting all say "Shipping First Name Required.The Shipping Address 1 field is required.
The Shipping City field is required.

What's my fatal flaw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store does not require shipping details to complete checkout.

It is hard to say for sure without seeing your template code but you will want to look at your checkout templates and make sure that you don't have `required="name|address1"` and any additional fields that are returning required. Using the shorthand "name" instead of "billing_name"  would require both shipping and billing names be filled out. The [docs](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html#require_fields) have more details on required fields.

You might also check in your Store > Settings > General that you have the
Default Shipping Address set to none and not "Billing same as Shipping Address"